# Getting CSS Div issue with ie9

Tags: css, html

Actually i have designed the template for one of  my games site. In the when i play the game  iam getting some problem in IE9 but no issues with other browsers. For clear understanding the issue please see [this](http://www.toon10.com/gameplay/KungFu_Panda_Racing_Challenge)

[image]
play page Code:

```
<div style="float:left">
<div class="gameContentsurround">
<div class="gameContentbg">
       <div class="gameDiv">
          <div align='center'>

            <!--game content here-->        
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="gameboxbelowheight"></div>
</div>
<div style='height:5px'></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="gameDesc">
<!--game description here-->
</div>
<div class="moregamesbg">
<div class="moregameswhitebg">
<!--more games section here-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:390px">
 <!--right column where actual issue comes here in IE9-->
</div>
```

right_column code:

```
<div class="playAdsWhiteBg">
    <div class='playAdsDiv'>
    <center>
        google ads

        </center>
    </div>

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style='height:2px'></div>
<!-- Ads END -->

<!-- Ads -->

<!--<div><?php echo SPONSORS_TITLE;?></div> -->

<div class="playAdsWhiteBg">
    <div class='playAdsDiv'>
    <center>
        google ads

        </center>
    </div>
 </div> 

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style='height:2px'></div>
<!-- Ads END -->

<!-- Comments Section -->
<div class="playAdsWhiteBg">
    <div class='playAdsDiv'>
    <div style="overflow:scroll">
fb comments
</div>
</div>
 </div> 

 <div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style='height:2px'></div>
<!-- Rating Section -->

<div class="ratethisgameWhiteBg">
    <div class='ratethisgameDiv'>
        rating system
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post your **relevant** code here on SO for us to be able to help you. And while you are at it please also write a proper problem description.

Comment: "iam getting some problem in IE9 but no issues with other browsers" What problem?

Comment: oops sorry...actually i added the image and url also please check the url in ie9. you will come to know..

Comment: Actually the div's must come side by side..but the problem is the right sided div comes after the main div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 390px` to `content`'s first child.

When you use floating elements you should always set their `width`

Comment: i have added the width already like this. <div style="float:right; width:390px">
 <?php include ('right_column.php'); ?>
</div>